# Call a Function at the End of video in Flow Player

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, flowplayer

I Need to call a function at the end of video using flow Player, how can i do it , the video is single file it is static video

Answer (score 2):

There are various events you can bind to in the flowplayer API.  One of them is `finish`.  If you bind to this you can them call your function.

**Example**

```
// gets the first player
var api = flowplayer();

// bind to the finish event
api.bind("finish", function(e, api){
    alert("Bacon");
});
```

For more information on the flowplayer API look at the [docs](http://flowplayer.org/docs/).

## Update

From your comment and Fiddle, I can see that you are using flowplayer Flash.  The answer above relates to the flowplayer HTML5 player and so would not work in your situation.

`onFinish` is a clip event therefore you must define the event inside the clip object.  In your Fiddle you are defining it outside of the clip object and it will not work in that way.  Only player events can be defined in the root of the player.

**Example**

```
flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", {
    clip: {
        onFinish: function() {
            alert("Bacon");
        }
    }
});
```

For more info see [flowplayer flash clip docs](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/events/clip.html)

Comment: I have tried below ,but there is no use ,please find my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/vamsikrishna981/Xb8Ks/

Comment: Please post your code.  Have you checked in your browser dev tools for any errors?  I assume that the video is playing correctly but the event is not firing.

Comment: @Bacon 
I have tried the below but nothing is html
But in fiddle all the events are firing i cant understand why it is behaving like this please check the below fiddles
http://jsfiddle.net/vamsikrishna981/ZNwkV/2/(working in fiddle)
http://jsfiddle.net/vamsikrishna981/H2Kmp/(working in fiddle& not working in local system)

Comment: The fiddles are working correctly, have you tried the exact same code on your local system?  If you have does the video play? Have the scripts downloaded correctly? Are there any errors in your browser dev tools.  Please check these.

Comment: I have not downloaded any files i am just making the reference from online, i have just copied the entire html in the below fiddle. check the below fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vamsikrishna981/H2Kmp/

Comment: Are you tied to using `flowplayer flash` or can you use `flowplayer HTML5` which is their current product.  It's certainly worth considering if you are getting nowhere with the flash only version.

Comment: We have to give support for ie8 also . so i am using flow player Flash version.

Comment: I am using `flowplayer HTML5` for a project which supports down to ie7.  `flowplayer HTML5` also has a flash fallback for browsers that do not support HTML5 video, or you can set it to only use flash if you do not have the right video formats.  I would recommend you give that a go.